# java springboot app on local container fails to access aws

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, docker

In my java app I'm creating the following S3 client :

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

My docker file :

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/myjar.jar /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "myjar.jar"]
```

I deployed my java app to a local container and I used the following run command :

```
$ docker run my-image-name --net="host" -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
```

But when my springboot app starts I'm getting an exception on the initalization of the s3Client :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint:
......
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
.....
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.

Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
```

As you can see, I passed the env variable AWS_DEFAULT_REGION (tried also AWS_REGION) but I'm still getting this error.

I'm using the following sdk version :

```
<aws-java-sdk-core.version>1.11.800</aws-java-sdk-core.version>
```

When I'm starting the app from inteliJ everything works gr8 since my config and credentials are configured in the .aws dir.

Maybe I need to expose any ports outside ?

Comment: try `-e var1=1 var2=2 ...`

Comment: without the secret access key ? still got exactly the same error

Comment: no, just combine all params in one `-e` option

Comment: done that, got the same error

Comment: hm, you can check which vars are present with `docker run ... -e ... env` https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-container-environment-variables

Comment: All the variables are set there

Comment: How difficult would it be to change your code to `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion(System.getEnv("AWS_REGION")).build()` at least for testing?  It's ugly and *requires* the environment variable be set but I've had this same type of issue and never found a simpler way.

Comment: Indeed I can do it, but it means that the environment variable must be set and then in environments that have the .aws dir wouldnt it prefer the env variables over the directory ? and How will it effect the app when it runs inside of an ec2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to start an EC2 node and deploy my code to there to test it. No idea why the region env isn't enough when pasting it to a local container.